# Confused on how to build a go project from source

Tags: go, workspace, geth

I'm trying to build the Ethereum node Geth: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
I cloned the project in my src folder ( in a folder called geth, should not metter, right? ) and when I try to run/compile does not find:

```
"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts"
"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore"
"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/utils"
```

and currently these file exists, as part of the project I'm trying to compile, so I don't actually understand why is referring the repository on line, and, in any case, why it does not work

Comment: "should not metter, right?" Wrong.

Comment: funny -2 votes for a legitimate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must clone the `geth` source in the exact folder in your `GOPATH`, actual path should be `GOPATH/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`.

Comment: thank you, suspected but did not find where the doc talk about it.